# Flash Google Maps: How to get id of a Marker onClick

Tags: flash, events, google-maps, maps

In Google Maps Flash API, When the user clicks, or hovers on a marker,  is there a way to dispatch an event containing the ID or lat/lon so this info can be used by the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Me stupid. This is easy: Here's the lat/lng of the marker:

```
var marker:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(list[i].lat, list[i].lon),
                new MarkerOptions({tooltip:list[i].name, 
                    icon:bm, iconOffset: new Point(-15, -15)}));

            marker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MapMouseEvent):void 
            {

                trace("latlng: " + e.latlng);
            });
```